# Searching a column in a unix file?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have the data file below:

```
136110828724515000007700877  
137110904734015000007700877  
138110911724215000007700877  
127110626724515000007700871  
127110626726015000007700871  
131110724724515000007700871  
134110814725015000007700871  
134110814734015000007700871  
104110122726027000001810072  
107110208724527000002900000
```

And I want to extract value of column 3 ie values of 6787714447.
I tried by using:-

```
awk "print $3" <filename>
```

but it didn't work. What should I use instead?

Comment: There's no visible separation between columns there. Please identify where the column boundaries are.  You might need to use `cut` with the `-c`. The string you say you're looking for doesn't appear in your sample data, which also doesn't help, unless you mean you want the values in column 3 concatenated into a single string with no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut is probably the simpler/cleaner option, but here two alternatives:

AWK version:

```
awk '{print substr($1, 3, 1) }' <filename>
```

Python version:

```
python -c 'print "\n".join(map(lambda x: x[2], open("<filename>").readlines()))'
```

EDIT: Please see 1_CR's comments and disregard this option in favour of his.

Comment: `python -c 'print "\n".join(x[2] for x in open("file"))'` for my money

Comment: it's not just about the size of the code. `readlines()` causes the entire file to be loaded into memory. The generator version does not

Comment: Good point, which while not new information, I entirely dismissed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is a better job for `cut`:

```
$ cut -c 3 < file
6
7
8
7
7
1
4
4
4
7
```

As per `man cut`:

> **-c, --characters=LIST**
>
> select only these characters

To make them appear all in the same line, pipe `tr -d '\n'`:

```
$ cut -c 3 < file | tr -d '\n'
6787714447
```

Or even to `sed` to have the new line at the end:

```
$ cut -c 3 < file | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/$/\n/'
6787714447
```

---

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ grep -oP "^..\K." file
6
7
8
7
7
1
4
4
4
7
```

---

with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -r 's/..(.).*/\1/' file
6
7
8
7
7
1
4
4
4
7
```

---

with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '{split ($0, a, ""); print a[3]}' file
6
7
8
7
7
1
4
4
4
7
```

Comment: And then you can join the lines e.g. using tr like so: `cut -c 3 /some/file | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Good one, @gerritzijlstra, if you don't mind I will include this nice suggestion into my answer. Thanks!

Comment: `awk -v FS= '{print $3}' file` should work as well, at a minimum with GNU awk